# Rails has_one :through. Building associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following data model in my Rails 2.3 application

```
class PortraitSubject
  has_many    :portraits
  has_one     :primary_portrait, :through => :portraits, :source => :asset, :conditions => ['portraits.primary = ?', true]
  has_many    :supplementary_portraits, :through => :portraits, :source => :asset, :conditions => ['portraits.primary = ?', false]

  ...
end

class Portrait
  belongs_to :portrait_subject
  belongs_to :asset

  ...
end
```

I want to build the associated proxy models using Rails but trying to build `primary_portrait` fails with an exception. I.e.

```
# This works
subject = PortraitSubject.new
subject.supplementary_portraits.build
subject.save

# This doesn't
subject = PortraitSubject.new
subject.build_primary_portrait
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `build_primary_portrait' for #<PortraitSubject:0x007ff16fe38948>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Looking through the Rails guides it looks like this should be possible with a `has_one` relationship. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you can build `:through` associations? If you are please provide a link

Answer (score 1):

You are going to go crazy with those naming conventions. A `PrimaryPortrait` and a `SecondaryPortrait` ought to be special cases of `Portrait` not the assets that belong to a `Portrait`. It's already breaking your design that you can't build one.

Try this:

```
class PortraitSubject
  has_many    :portraits
  has_one     :primary_portrait, :conditions => {:primary => true}
  has_many    :supplementary_portraits, :conditions => {:primary => false}

  has_many    :portrait_assests, :through => :portraits
  has_one     :primary_portrait_asset, :through => :primary_portrait
  has_many    :supplementary_portrait_assets, :through => :supplementary_portraits

end
```

then, if you need to build a `primary_portait_asset` write an instance method

```
def build_primary_portrait_asset
  primary_portrait || build_primary_portrait
  primary_portrait.asset || primary_portrait.build_asset
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the following.

```
class Portrait
  belongs_to :portrait_subject
  belongs_to :asset

  ...
end
```

-

```
class PrimaryPortrait < Portrait
  ...
end
```

-

```
class SupplementaryPortraits < Portrait
  ...
end
```

-

```
class PortraitSubject
  has_one     :primary_portrait
  has_many    :supplementary_portraits
  ...
end
```

This follows rails design patterns more closely. You will have to add a type column though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest splitting this into two associations:

```
class PortraitSubject
  has_many    :portraits
  has_one     :primary_portrait, :class_name => "Portrait", :conditions => ['portraits.primary = ?', true]
  has_one     :primary_portrait_asset, :through => :primary_portrait, :source => :asset

  has_many    :supplementary_portraits, :class_name => "Portrait", :conditions => ['portraits.primary = ?', false]
  has_many     :supplementary_portrait_assets, :through => :supplementary_portraits, :source => :asset

  ...
end
```

Then you can use `subject.build_primary_portrait` to create the portrait model, and access its asset through `subject.primary_portrait_asset`.